# Is there a way to test in-app browsers / safari browsers in Cucumber / Capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, capybara, browser-automation

I am still pretty new to using **Cucumber** and **Capybara**. But I have seen that I can use `Capybara.page.current_window.resize_to(x,y)` to modify the window to the size I want to, but only when I am using Firefox/Chrome.

Is there a way for me to run my tests accurately, but use a in-app browser (like the Facebook App browser) and see the results?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The in-app browser on iOS is using the WebKit engine. The size of the in-app browser window depends on the device it is running on and the size of the webview it is displayed in. You shouldn't try to set it to a specific size, but just make sure that you use a mobile viewport size (depends on your targeted devices).

If you render your pages in Chrome it will be close to the thing your users might see using the in-app browser. Does that help?

> That will give me back the most accurate representation of the Facebook / in-app browser?

I don't know for sure, but I cannot think of a better way.

Comment: So if I continue to use the chrome webkit and then use Capybara.page.current_window.resize_to(x,y) to the size I want. That will give me back the most accurate representation of the Facebook / in-app browser? Sorry if my question sounds extremely basic, I just would like to double check!